# Why grails compile command shows :compileJava NO-SOURCE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grails

I am using intellij to run a grails framework project. I use `grails create-app app-name` to create a project but when I use `grails compile` command It shows the following.

```
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildProperties
:processResources
:classes

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: Do you mean: why does it even try to compile java files or do you actually have a src/main/java direcotry and are there java files in there and they won't get compiled?

Comment: I dont have have a src/main/java direcotry